# Autoflow images in InDesign table

Tags: adobe-indesign, automation, tables

Is there a way to insert multiple images at once in a InDesign table column (each image being assigned its own cell) , just like you would "autoflow" text in a text box? This also implies that new pages with the same table layout would automatically add themselves should the capacity of a table's column be exceeded.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few ways to go about this. Each has it's own strengths and weaknesses. Here are the three that best meet your needs as I understand them in order of likelihood.

1. Data Merge (vanilla)

Load all your info into a spreadsheet, set the paragraph style up like a table then do a stock standard data merge. This is fast and easy but is functionally limited.

2. Data Merge (with [table add on](http://indesignsecrets.com/using-data-merge-to-create-a-table-for-a-directory.php))

I didn't try this script but it looks like what you need with the tables.

3. XML

You can use the inDesign XML import to bring in data, styles, images and bring significantly more functionality. Keep in mind that it can be a massive headache as the feature still lacks polish.